# Would destroying rupees be an international offense?

Tags: criminal-law, international, india, currency

In the Bill No. 174 of 2023 - "THE BHARATIYA NAGARIK SURAKSHA (SECOND) SANHITA, 2023", it is stated that:

"Mischief causing loss or damage to any property or fine, or both, including property of Government or Local Authority"

is a criminal offense which might imply a fine or prison time.

So:

1. Does this apply to accidentally damaging banknotes (rupees) as those are considered government property?
2. Is it actionable in the case those banknotes have been damaged in another country?

Comment: It seems to me that the word "Mischief" would preclude "accidentally damaging".

Comment: @JBentley I tend to agree, though I suppose it's possible that it might include accidents attributable to negligence.

Comment: @phoog, if it stated "*negligence causing loss or damage...*" I would agree.  Otherwise the matter of intent would need to be established in court, right?

Comment: If you receive a banknote in commerce, do you not own it?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this apply to accidentally damaging banknotes (rupees) as those
> are considered government property?

No.

What makes you think that banknotes are government property in the context of this law?

The fact that the government issued the notes does not make them government property. In the same vein, a Ford sedan is not the property of Ford just because it manufactured it. Currency is owned legally by the person who is in possession of it for almost all purposes, including this one. Once it is circulated, it is no longer government property.

A banknote is evidence of a debt owed by the Indian government, not its property. The destruction of a banknote is economically beneficial to the Indian government, not harmful to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this apply to accidentally damaging banknotes (rupees) as those are considered government property?

No.  The bill specifically states "*Mischief* causing..." which implies the intent to destroy.  Accidents are not normally considered to be a criminal offense because they lack intent.

> Is it actionable in the case those banknotes have been damaged in another country?

It depends...  If you are a citizen of India it is likely that Indian law applies to you regardless of your geographical location.  However, for non-Indian citizens the answer would be no.  (*unless there was an international treaty between nations stating otherwise*)

Consider that if I brought a bank note back to the United States and was feeling mischievous and destroyed it.  While I might be breaking an Indian law, (as it is written) I would not be breaking any laws in the jurisdiction having authority over me, and since *India has not been granted authority to unilaterally make policy over other sovereign nations*, [if I do not travel to India] the laws of India do not apply to me.  Therefore it would not be "actionable".

An individual destroying a few Rupees simply does not rise to the level of international crime that someone might be extradited for.
However, wanton off-shore destruction of large quantities of Indian cash in an attempt to disrupt the economy would be a different story, so you may want to clarify the scope of your question.

Comment: Why do you assume that this Indian law doesn't apply in the US?

Comment: @amo, one word: Jurisdiction.

Comment: Germany has outlawed murdering Germans everywhere in the world. India could have chosen to outlow destroying rupees everywhere in the world, too, if she feels like it.

Comment: Jurisdiction (in this context) simply means the geographical extent of a particular rule, and that can be defined however the legislation drafter wants. While it is *unusual* for a rule's jurisdiction to extend beyond a country's borders, it is entirely possible and examples do exist. See [Section 72 of the Sexual Offences Act 2003](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/72) for an example. So, "the laws of India do not apply to me" is incorrect. What matters is whether there is a law against destroying currency which has worldwide jurisdiction.

Comment: @JBentley. "*Jurisdiction ... can be defined however the legislation drafter wants.*" Sure, they can define it however they want, but that doesn't mean they have any actual authority, or that a geographical overreach would have any real effect. For example, if I say that my house rule of taking off shoes at the front door also applies to you, does that mean that it is correct to say that it does, even if I have no means of enforcing it?

Comment: Anyway, jurisdiction encompasses more than mere geography - (e.g. subject matter jurisdiction, in personam jurisdiction, etc.) My point is that merely claiming jurisdiction outside your borders doesn't mean you have it.  P.S. I have made a few edits to the second half that will perhaps make it more acceptable. Please let me know if you have any suggestions for improvement.

Comment: @JBentley The case that extraterritorial effect is not intended is heightened by the fact that the law in question isn't a law about destroying currency, it is a law about destroying government owned property.

Comment: @ohwilleke, Thanks.  Given this comment, as well as your answer, a better question would have been "*are Rupees considered government property?*"  Much hullabaloo over a faulty assertion in the question.  Geez... (eye roll)

Comment: @Arno I was aware that US law makes it illegal for US citizens to kill other US citizens anywhere, meaning they will try to extradite you and prosecute you. That German law, does that apply to German murderers or any murderer?

Comment: @MichaelHall "*Sure, they can define it however they want, but that doesn't mean they have any actual authority, or that a geographical overreach would have any real effect.*" You are conflating legal jurisdiction with enforcement. The effect will feel very real if you travel to the country whose laws you broke and get arrested at the airport. "jurisdiction encompasses more than mere geography " - yes, and that is exactly why I wrote "jurisdiction **(in this context)**", to make clear that I wasn't referring to the other meanings of the word.

Comment: For an example of a case where there are clearly real effects, consider the ICC's arrest warrant for Putin. Russia is not a member of the ICC, and so it cannot enforce the arrest warrant there. However, 123 countries are members. Putin effectively cannot travel to a majority of the world without risking an arrest. This is generally believed to be the reason he canceled his recent trip to South Africa.

Comment: @gnasher729 German law applies if one of murderer and victim is German (or if the murder takes place in Germany).

Comment: @JBentley, “*You are conflating legal jurisdiction with enforcement. The effect will feel very real if you travel to the country whose laws you broke and get arrested at the airport.*”  Yes, that’s true, but there is an enforcement element in every law, otherwise it is as pointless as the resolution our city council drafted condemning actions in the middle east.  (*Yes, they actually did that… and we paid them while they did.*)

Comment: Anyway, neither the question nor my answer said anything about traveling back to India after the act.  My answer came from my perspective, as a US citizen on US soil, doing something to my personal property, and with no intent to ever travel to India.  Regarding jurisdiction, you need more than simple geography to prosecute someone, correct?  **In this context**, (or any, right?) to prosecute don’t you also need in personam and subject matter jurisdiction?  Are there others?

Comment: And finally, you dodged the question I asked to put “applicability” into the perspective I based my answer on.  I will ask again:  If I make a rule that requires you, JBentley, to remove your shoes when you enter your house in the UK, would you say that 1.)  My rule DOES apply to you, I simply lack the ability to enforce it because I live in the US, or 2.) My rule does NOT apply to you because I lack any authority to make such rules for you in your own house?

Comment: P.S. I added "[if I do not travel to India] *the laws of India do not apply to me*"